# How can I embed Twilio's sms service in an html file?

Tags: javascript, html, twilio

All I found was with php and node.js (which is based on js, so it should be fine), but I got across this library:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="//media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.4/twilio.min.js"></script>
```

What is the relavant JS code to make a "send sms" request?
This is the php I found:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
$client = new Client($sid, $token);
$client->messages->create(
 '+15558675309', // number to send to
 array(
 'from' => '+15017250604', // your Twilio number
 'body' => "There’s something strange in my neighborhood. I don’t know who to call. Send help!"
 )
);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We don't recommend that you use the Twilio REST API for sending SMS messages within a public HTML page. If you do so, you will expose your account credentials publicly and a malicious attacker could steal them and send messages or phone calls on your behalf, using up your credit and potentially spamming people.

The JavaScript library you found there is for you to use to [make phone calls from within the browser using WebRTC](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/twilio-js). This is built to not leak your credentials as you need to [generate a token server side](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/capability-tokens) that can be used to authenticate users.

I recommend you check out the [SMS quick start guides](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart?filter-product=sms) in a language of your choice to see how you can write server side code to send messages.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm aware of the dangers and already using tokens to auto send Emails. What I'm missing is SMS\Phone calls. I'm writing a free app to help parents keep track of their children arriving to kindergarten. I get an email every 5 minutes, updating me with each kid's situation, but I can't spend my day making phone calls to parents, so twillio sounded like a good choice. I opened the link you said but is doesn't show a Javascript solution. Many others, but not pure JS.

Comment: What language are you using for the server side component of your application then?

Comment: It's all javascript. I'm using a JS add on in order to send the email with the variables I need.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand your setup here. Do you have a Node.js server that is running JavaScript? Is everything happening inside the browser, but you're only running it on your own machine? I'd love to help, I just don't know the starting point here.

Comment: Thanks. I got an html page which I converted to an apk via phonegap. On my html page I got all the variables for the children's state - whether they have arrived or not, and then I have a set timeout function that sends the variables to my email address via this JS add-in: www.smtpjs.com, so I know who arrived and who did not.

Comment: Ok, so you don't have a server side component at the moment. SMTPJS allows you to encrypt your credentials and lock to a single domain, which is a reasonable solution. Twilio does not offer that. We encourage you to have a server side component that calls our API that you can then interact with using an AJAX call from your JavaScript. If you don't want to host your own server, check out [Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/functions) which allows you to run Node.js on our infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks for this info. However I'm not very familiar with server side. What is the best way to be able to use twilio, learn node.js? Thanks again.

Comment: If you're already comfortable with JavaScript, then Node.js is probably a pretty good way to get to know this part of the Twilio API (and has the benefit that you could use Twilio Functions, which must be written in Node.js).

Comment: What would be the best place to start learning the basics of node.js? My university's courses don't cover it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know the best place. There's loads of beginner tutorials, video courses and books out there and it probably just requires you to pick one that you can afford (or find a free one) that is going to suit your learning style. I didn't learn from a basics course, just sort of taught myself over time, so I can't really help there.